# Drupal views, show node title as table header

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

How to display one node type title as views table top header and another node type title as table left side title.

Let's consider 2 node types Services and Plans. Node Services will have entity reference to node Plans. Now I have to display it like this,

```
================================

Services/Plans | plan1 | plan2 | plan3 | plan4

================================

service1 | Yes | No | Yes | Yes

service2 | No | Yes | Yes | No

service3 | Yes | No | No | Yes
```

Here `plan1`, `plan2`, `plan3`, `plan4` will be the nodes of type Plans. `service1`, `service2`, `service3`, `service4` will be nodes of type Services.

Any suggestions how to achieve this using Drupal 7 Views 3 or is there any contributed modules?

Answer (score 0):

Create custom template file(s) for your view and you can achieve anything you like. Open "Advance" section when editing view and click "Theming information" to get templates name suggestions.

Comment: Custom theming is the only way or is there any modules available to achieve this?

Comment: Easiest one. When you have too specific request you must go for custom solution.